# How to convert a record or list into JSON format using python?

Tags: python, json, neo4j

I am trying to convert a list into JSON using Python. The result from a query looks something like this :

**Output:**

```
[<Record r=<Relationship id=106 nodes=(<Node id=71 labels=frozenset({'TBox'}) properties={'identifier': '', 'ontology_level': 'lower', 'neo4jImportId': '105', 'html_info': '', 'namespace': 'car', 'admin': '', 'description': 'remove', 'sing': '', 'pl': '', 'title': 'BMProcessor', 'version': 'v6.0'}>, <Node id=59 labels=frozenset({'TBox'}) properties={'identifier': '', 'ontology_level': 'lower', 'neo4jImportId': '93', 'html_info': '', 'namespace': 'car', 'admin': '', 'description': 'A DataProcessor which represents a ML algorithm', 'sing': '', 'pl': '', 'title': 'LearningProcessor', 'version': 'v6.0'}>) type='subclass_of' properties={}> b=<Node id=59 labels=frozenset({'TBox'}) properties={'identifier': '', 'ontology_level': 'lower', 'neo4jImportId': '93', 'html_info': '', 'namespace': 'car', 'admin': '', 'description': 'A DataProcessor which represents a ML algorithm', 'sing': '', 'pl': '', 'title': 'LearningProcessor', 'version': 'v6.0'}> n=<Node id=71 labels=frozenset({'TBox'}) properties={'identifier': '', 'ontology_level': 'lower', 'neo4jImportId': '105', 'html_info': '', 'namespace': 'car', 'admin': '', 'description': 'remove', 'sing': '', 'pl': '', 'title': 'BMProcessor', 'version': 'v6.0'}>>]
```

**Function :**

```
def runQuery(query):
  pprint.pprint(connection.execute(query))
```

When I perform a simple `json.dumps()` it return with `TypeError: Object of type is not JSON serializable`

I want to print a JSON format out of this. How can I do so?

Comment: https://neo4j.com/developer/python-movie-app/#_going_through_the_endpoints

Comment: @FloLie Thanks for your suggestion, I tried to serialize the list but unfortunately it does not seem to work. Could you elaborate?

Comment: 1) Please give a sample of what you want the JSON to look like. There is no trivial representation for nodes and relationships in JSON. 2) are you using py2neo or the official neo4j driver?

Comment: 1) I would like to have something like this as output - [this](https://pastebin.com/djhV6CQL). 2) I am using the official neo4j driver. There is no description of JSON representation in the whole API documentation. @RouvenB.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `result.data()` which is a dictionary.

You can also iterate over the records in the cursor and convert one by one, and extract the fields you want, which is what the [linked example](https://neo4j.com/developer/python-movie-app/#_whats_going_on_with_the_serializer) above does - pass the cursor and use the `blob['field']` syntax

```py
def serialize_genre(genre):
    return {
        'id': genre['id'],
        'name': genre['name'],
    }
```